# while uploading photo to Facebook CurlExeption 26 appears

Tags: php, facebook

Im using unity3d to make a screenshot and pload it to facebook. Because my app will be cross platform it succesfully uploades it to a php script, which will pass it to facebook through the browser. While testing on XAMPP(Windows) I get this error:

Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "temp/528056320screenShot.png"

thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\base_facebook.php** on line **994**

this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_FILES['theFile']))
{
$img_src = "temp/" . $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
print $img_src;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'], $img_src);
  print "   moved";
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
print "no ssl";
// allow uploads
//$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
print " file upload on";

// add a status message
$photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST',
        array(
                'source' =>  '@'. $img_src ,//blijkbaar klopt het pad niet
                'message' => 'This photo came from my app.'
        )
);
var_dump($photo);
var_dump($img_src);
print "succes";

}
else
{
print "Faail";
}
?>
```

Does someone know a solution to this problem? it seems like I'm making just a minor mistake and can't figure it out. the Image gets uploaded to the folder and i can view it after the script finished running.

Comment: Was the upload progress successfull? Does the file exist? Is the path correct? Do you have read-access to it?

Comment: The only thing I coudn't properly check is the read acces. Gave everyone read acces but can be windows related issues. Path is correct and file does exist

Comment: Try an absolute path then and escape it properly, also Windows does use "\" IMO.